# Visual Studio 2017: Want to get the full path of $(S_LIBS)

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I want to get the full path of $(S_LIBS), can someone explain me how?

Comment: What is `$(S_LIBS)`? Please [clarify](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48598006/edit).

Comment: Also, at which place do you plan to use this info? $(S_LIBS) seems to be a macro (system or project-defined) and it should auto-expand automatically on build stage.